# Expression of trigonometric functions simplification

Tags: trigonometry

For $0 < x < 1$ I have $$\arctan\left( \frac{1}{\tan(\pi x)}\right)$$ How can this be simplified?

Comment: Did you wonder about $$\arctan(1/t)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(t)$$ and $$\arctan \tan z = z $$?

Comment: Yes that was the thing I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** For positive $x$, one has: $\arctan(1/x)+\arctan(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$.